# Servicestack - Ormlite - high volume data loading

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am getting some issues with Servicestack and OrmLite in high data loading scenarios.

Specifically,
1. I have a list of 1000 000 + entities
2. I would like to insert them into Db (using Sql Server) if record does not exist yet

Thus,

```
public class Entity  
{  
  [Autoincrement]  
  public int Id {get;set;}  
  public string Name {get;set;}  
  public string Address {get;set;}  
}
```

Now for the import logic,

```
List<Entity> entities = oneMillionEntities.ToList();  
foreach (var entity in entities)  
{   
    if (!db.Exists<Entity>(ar => ar.Address == entity.Address))  
    {  
        db.Save(entity);  
    }  
}
```

Issue is that quite often db is still busy with save action thus db.Exists does not always produce correct result. What is the best way of handling these scenarios?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "db is still busy with save action"?  Are you doing something asynchronously and getting read or write locks?

Comment: Getting read or write locks... Is there a better way of doing it? Or handling db locks...

Comment: Personally, with the need to process 1,000,000 items, I would probably NOT use OrmLite.  ORM's are great for CRUD operations, but for bulk operations, you can get some amazing speed by using `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: agreed that SqlBulkCopy will probably get the best speed. OrmLite does not support this out of the box, therefore InsertAll I guess is the best answer for now.

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` is straightforward and bypass some controls (like triggers). If you really need performance, you can take a look at https://gist.github.com/zelid/6965002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
// Prepare SqlExpression
var ev = Db.From<Entity>().Select(p => p.Address).GroupBy(p => p.Address);

// Execute SqlExpression and transform result to HashSet
var dbAddresses = Db.SqlList(ev).ToHashSet();

// Filter local entities and get only local entities with different addresses
var filteredEntities = oneMillionEntities.Where(p => 
!dbAddresses.Contains(p.Address));

// Bulk insert
db.InsertAll(filteredEntities.ToList());
```

Comment: That inserts all items in the list -- which is not what the OP wanted.  He's doing an address check and only inserts items with an address that doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: The example is here to show one method call is better than one million. So he can filter entities list before and pass the filtered view to InsertAll method.